# I am unable to install ApiGen om a mac

Tags: macos, apigen

I am unable to install ApiGen om a mac.
I did everything as instructed on apigen.org:

```
wget http://apigen.org/apigen.phar
chmod +x apigen.phar
mv apigen.phar /usr/local/bin/apigen
apigen --version
```

And this is the result I get everytime!

```
sh-3.2# wget http://apigen.org/apigen.phar
--2015-02-12 16:20:30--  http://apigen.org/apigen.phar
Resolving apigen.org... 192.30.252.153
Connecting to apigen.org|192.30.252.153|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /apigen.phar [following]
--2015-02-12 16:20:30--  http://apigen.org/apigen.phar
Connecting to apigen.org|192.30.252.153|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.apigen.org/apigen.phar [following]
--2015-02-12 16:20:30--  http://www.apigen.org/apigen.phar
Resolving www.apigen.org... 23.235.43.133
Connecting to www.apigen.org|23.235.43.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 793275 (775K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'apigen.phar'

apigen.phar                       100%[===============================================================>] 774.68K  --.-KB/s   in 0.1s   

2015-02-12 16:20:30 (5.51 MB/s) - 'apigen.phar' saved [793275/793275]

sh-3.2# chmod +x apigen.phar
sh-3.2# mv apigen.phar /usr/local/bin/apigen
sh-3.2# apigen --version

**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar file "/usr/local/bin/apigen"' in /usr/local/bin/apigen:11
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/apigen(11): Phar::mapPhar('apigen.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/apigen on line 11
```

Can some one tell me what i'm doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Your installation of PHP is missing the zlib extension - repair that and try again

Comment: Have you tried installing Phar extension?

Comment: I don't need to: [phar installation](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php)
I run PHP Version 5.6.3